# Wireless earphones with great device pairing and reconnecting

Tags: earphones

After a little investigation and finding a balance between price and features, I got a great deal getting the [Xiaomi Air2 SE](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001060321019.html). They seemed great on paper, but after trying them, their greatest feature is that they are cheap and they sound okay. In other situations, that would be enough for me to return them, but I decided to compromise, even if the play/pause feature is poorly designed.

But what I couldn't stand with is the pairing system. In theory, putting them in the box, closing it, and opening it again is enough for them to start on discover mode… unless you have them paired in another device already. In that case, they automatically pair back to what you had before. Okay, turn off the 1st device Bluetooth, close the lid, open it again. It may take up to 20 seconds or several tries for the 2nd device to recognize them. That's okay, it's their first pairing. Let's switch back to connect to the 1st device. On the first try, it unpaired from the device, tried pairing again (on its own), and told me the passkey was incorrect. Worst thing? This 1st device is a Xiaomi Note 8 Pro, which in theory has extra pairing capabilities with this device (yet they don't work). So, to sum up:

Due to my working process, I move back and forth between different devices, connect to one, then to another, back to the first, etc. I'm done with cables and headsets (I had some Marshall Major II Bluetooth, and they were expensive, tight, break easily, and lost the wireless capabilities after some time. No more). **Are there any relatively cheap wireless earphones that don't suck at pairing and reconnecting?**